# Page layout - removing footer

Tags: 8, theming

How do I remove the grey footer on my site? It's using the Bartik theme.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The footer is hardcoded, especially Bartik. It's a default theme of Drupal.

1. You can alter the color of the footer under admin/appearance/settings/bartik
2. Make a subtheme and alter the css
3. Or, for minor changes, use the module CSS injector